# can i fetch a custom metabox data in another page or post type?

Tags: php, theme-development, metabox

I need to fitch a metabox field data in another page ,

```
$headabouttitle1 = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'head_title1', true);
```

this is how i fetch it in the same page , I need to fitch it in another page template , how can i do it

Answer (score -1):

Outside the loop you can use this:

```
global $post;
$headabouttitle1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'head_title1', true);
```

Comment: That's still the same post as `get_the_id()` is using. The question is about a **different** post.